# Showing $g(x) = -2\pi x e^{-\pi x^2} = O(1/x^2)$ for $x \rightarrow \pm \infty$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to understand Landau's notation and wanted to prove that

$$g(x) = -2\pi x e^{-\pi x^2} = O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) \qquad \qquad \text{ for }  x \rightarrow \pm \infty.$$

In the $x \rightarrow + \infty$ case, I think I have to prove that there is an $M > 0$ and $N > 0$ such that for all $x > N$ it holds that

$$\bigg|-2 \pi x e^{-\pi x^2}\bigg| \leq \frac{M}{x^2}.$$

But I'm stuck here as I don't seem to be able to prove that $2 \pi x^3 e^{-\pi x^2} \leq M.$

Answer (score 2):

If $|x|>1$ then
$$
e^{\pi x^2 }  = 1 + \pi x^2  + \frac{{\pi ^2 x^4 }}{{2!}} +  \cdots  > \frac{{\pi ^2 x^4 }}{{2!}} > x^4>|x|^3,
$$
i.e.,
$$
e^{ - \pi x^2 }  < \frac{1}{|x|^3}
$$
for $|x|>1$. Then
$$
\left| { - 2\pi xe^{ - \pi x^2 } } \right| < 2\pi \frac{1}{x^2}
$$
for $|x|>1$.

Answer (score 1):

Because $\lim_{x \to +\infty}|-2\pi x^3 \exp (-\pi x^2)| = 0,$ we know we can find *that* $N$ such that for any $x > N$ we have $|-2\pi x^3 \exp (-\pi x^2)| \leq M.$ This already proves it.

In general, when $$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{||f(x)||}{h(x)}$$ exists (with $h(x)$ strictly positive for all $x\neq a$ in a neighbourhoud of $a$) and it's finite, so $$0 \leq \lim_{x\to a} \frac{||f(x)||}{h(x)} < +\infty, $$you can say that $f(x) = O(h(x))$ for $x \to a.$ This can be helpful in many cases, and it can also be helpful to get some intuition for what it means for $f(x)$ to be $O(h(x))$ for $x\to a.$

In the case of small o, it's the same thing but the limit *has* to be $0$ (*if* it exists). In the case of $\Omega$ it's kind of the opposite of big O. It has to be $$0 < \lim_{x\to a} \frac{||f(x)||}{h(x)} \leq +\infty,$$ again *if* it exists and in the case of $\Theta$ we want that the limit is a strictly positive number that isn't infinite.

Comment: This seems to correspond to what's written in our course notes. One question though, can we compute the first limit by saying that the exponential goes faster than any polynomial? Or how would we really compute this?

Comment: @Geigercounter. That depends on what "level" you are and what's the purpose of the course, I'd say. If you're an engineering student, then that suffices. If you've already covered limits very well in a course that precedes this as a maths student, then it's also okay to just say that. If you're just getting into real analysis and the point of the course *is* making $(\epsilon, \delta)$-type proofs, then you'd probably have to be more specific.